# flask praetorian AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-praetorian

Hey can anyone one help me

I'm making an api with orm sqlalchemy and authantication with flask-praetorian

I'm having :

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Looks like it's not even creating a new User object.
It shows this error when I try to register a new user,
and shows some problem with
`new_user = User(`  -- in register route.

This is my model file :

```
from . import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(20))
    roles = db.Column(db.Text)

    @property
    def identity(self):
        return self.id

    @property
    def rolenames(self):
        try:
            return self.roles.split(",")
        except Exception:
            return []

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.hashed_password

    @classmethod
    def lookup(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username=username).one_or_none()

    @classmethod
    def identify(cls, id):
        return cls.query.get(id)

    def is_valid(self):
        return self.is_active
```

This is my routes file
on
`new_user = User(` it is showing some problem

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
from . import db, guard
from .models import Movie, User
import flask_praetorian

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@main.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    username = req.get('username', None)
    email = req.get('email', None)
    password = req.get('password', None)
    new_user = User(
        username=username,
        password=guard.hash_password(password),
        roles='operator'
    )
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    guard.send_registration_email(email, user=new_user)
    ret = {'message': 'successfully sent registration email to user {}'.format(
        new_user.username
    )}
    return (jsonify(ret), 201)
```